# Highstock granularity of x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My highstock chart chokes on the x-axis labels once I get down any more granular than about 1 day - that is, the data renders properly but the x-axis (time) labels don't seem to update, and become more sparse as I zoom in until they disappear completely. (See images)

Here is a fiddle at a larger time interval where the labels show as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/uhpn8Ljp/2/

Here is a fiddle for the smaller intervals where they don't display: http://jsfiddle.net/4r39730h/1/

I have this as my data setup when the data is received:

```
return {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline',
        zoomType: 'x',
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    navigator: {
        adaptToUpdatedData: false,
        series: {
            data: masterSeriesDateValues || dateValues,
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            minPadding: 0.1,
            maxPadding: 0.1,
            labels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
            tickWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
        },
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true,
        inputBoxStyle: { right: '65px', position: 'absolute' },
        buttons: [{
            type: 'second',
            count: 1,
            text: '1s',
        }, {
            type: 'minute',
            count: 1,
            text: '1min',
        }, {
            type: 'hour',
            count: 1,
            text: '1h',
        }, {
            type: 'day',
            count: 1,
            text: '1d',
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m',
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y',
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All',
        }],
        selected: rangeSelectorIndex,
        inputDateFormat: dateFormat,
        inputEditDateFormat: dateFormat,
        inputBoxWidth: 170,
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false,
    },

    xAxis: {
        min: xAxisStart,
        max: xAxisEnd,
        minRange: 1, // one millisecond
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return `${this.points[0].series.name} : ${(display === 'count' ? this.y : formatBytes(this.y))}`;
        },
    },

    series: [{
        id: 'itemSize',
        name: display === 'count' ? 'Count of Items' : 'Size of Items',
        data: dateValues,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false,
        },
    }],
};
```

I also add a few events and labels on render:

```
xAxis.events = {
    afterSetExtremes: this.afterSetExtremes.bind(this),
};
chart.events = { selection: function (ev) {
    that.handleRangeSelection.call(this, ev, that);
} };
chartConfig.tooltip = {
    formatter: function () {
        let label;
        if (display === 'count') {
            label = this.points[0].series.name + ': ' + this.y;
        } else {
            label = this.points[0].series.name + ': ' + formatBytes(this.y);
        }
        return label;
    },
};
```

In a previous implementation of the app, I was seeing smaller and smaller intervals down to milliseconds, and I just copied and pasted the configuration so I don't understand what could be different.

[image: At approximately 24-hour zoom]

[image: 2 hour zoom]
[image: under 1 second zoom]

Comment: This might be caused by the code you have not posted. Could you recreate a minimal, verifiable demo? For example in JSFiddle?

Comment: For the smaller intervals: http://jsfiddle.net/4r39730h/1/
Larger intervals: http://jsfiddle.net/uhpn8Ljp/2/

Comment: If you will set for xAxis `ordinal` to false, then navigator will work better - show an actual range which is set - and labels will work properly. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4r39730h/2/